# How can I extract the first folder from a URL?

Tags: .net, regex

I need to improve the method below.

The idea is to extract the first folder of a URL if it exists. The URLs may be passed with or without a domain, that is to say, `http://www.examplecom/es/test/test.aspx`, `http://example.com/es/test/`, or simply `/us/xxx/xxx.aspx`.

```
public string ExtractURL(string url)
{
    string result = "";
    try
    {
        string[] urlSplitted = url.Split("//".ToCharArray());
        //si encontramos /
        if (urlSplitted.Length > 0)
        {
            string strFin = urlSplitted[urlSplitted.GetUpperBound(0) - 1];
            //comprobamos que exista algo
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strFin))
            {
                result = url;
            }
            else
            {
                //devuelvo la url hasta /ES o /EN
                result = url.Substring(0,url.ToLower().IndexOf("/" +strFin.ToLower()));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result = url;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        result = "";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You haven't said what's wrong with the method you've got now. What isn't working?

Comment: The idea was to have sth more compressed, regex comes always well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to solve this with a regular expression (as you tagged your question "regex"), try this:

```
public string ExtractURL(string url)
{
  return Regex.Match(url, "(?<!/)/[^/?#]+").Value;
}
```

This regex works on absolute URLs, and on relative URLs that begin with a slash.  If it also needs to work on relative URLs without a slash, try this:

```
public string ExtractURL(string url)
{
  Regex.Match(url, @"(\w*:(//[^/?#]+)?/)?(?<folder>[^/?#]+)").Groups["folder"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Cast to a Uri and then use the Segments property. You'll actually want the second segment because the first is just the leading slash.

```
public string ExtractURL(string url)
{
    Uri webAddress = null;
    string firstFolder = null;
    if (Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out webAddress))
    {
        if (!webAddress.IsAbsoluteUri)
        {
            webAddress = new Uri(Request.Url, url);
        }
        if (webAddress.Segments.Length >= 2)
        {
            firstFolder = webAddress.Segments[1];
        }
    }
    return firstFolder;
}
```

Comment: sorry, you can not use segments for relative urls, and the property Count doesnot exist, it is length. The important problem is the first.

Comment: True. Add a check for relative path and you're golden. Example fixed to reflect that.

Comment: I think you cannot use Segments for relative urls. Thanks.

Comment: That's not a relative Url any longer because it's made an absolute url by the webAddress = new Uri(Request.Url, url);

Comment: Ok, this is true it is made an absolute url, oops!, I prefer the regex solution, because to convert to absolute url to extract a part is not so efficient but i point this answer because it's another very good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class to pre-parse the Uri and extract the relative path with LocalPath property. Then use String.split().

Answer (score 0):

```
public string ExtractURL(string URL)
    {
        string result = "";
        try
        {
            httpindex = URL.ToLower().IndexOf("http://");
            if (httpindex > 0)
            {
                URL = URL.Substring(0, 6);
            }
            URL = URL.ToLower().TrimStart("http://".ToCharArray());
            string[] urlArray = URL.Split('/');
            if (urlArray.Length > 1)
            {
                    result = urlArray[1];
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            result = "";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

That should do what you want I think

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sergii Volchkov and I think using System.Uri is the right way to go but instead of using string.split you may want to use Path.GetParentDirectory() on the local path.

Comment: This method does not exist, there is  Path.GetPathRoot but it does not work

Comment: Whoops sorry I meant use "GetDirectoryName()". You may have to use this method multiple times to get to the first folder.